# Regular expression to generate a conditional push

Tags: arrays, perl, awk, push

**INPUT**

```
fish \t 1 \t red

fish \t 2 \t blue

fish \t 4 \t green

dog \t 1 \t blue

dog \t 3 \t yellow

cat \t 3 \t orange
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
fish \t red  \t blue \t _______ \t green

dog  \t blue \t ____ \t yellow 

cat  \t ____ \t ____ \t orange
```

I wish to generate an array while keeping the order given by column 2 from input file.
In this example, since there is no line in which column 2 = 3, I wish to push with " ".

The actual file I am working with has a maximum of 98 position to fill in one array.

Any suggestions from Perl experts?

Thank you!

Comment: I ended up finding the solution in perl:  <br/> #!/usr/bin/perl
open DOC, $filename
while ($line = <DOC>) {
    @columns = split('\s', $line);
if ($columns[0] ne $animal) {
        &PRINT();
        &RESET();
    }
    $color[100] = (undef);
    $color[$columns[1]-1] = $columns [2];
}
&PRINT();
}
close DOC;
exit;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'\t' '
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++k] = $1 }
NR==1 { min = max = $2 }
{
    min = ($2<min?$2:min)
    max = ($2>max?$2:max)
    map[$1,$2] = $3
}
END {
    for (k=1;k in keys;k++) {
        key = keys[k]
        printf "%s", key
        for (c=min; c<=max; c++) {
            val = ( (key,c) in map ? map[key,c] : "___" )
            printf "%s%s", FS, val
        }
        print ""
    }
}
' file
fish    red     blue    ___     green
dog     blue    ___     yellow  ___
cat     ___     ___     orange  ___
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you can change `"___"` to `FS`):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR==1 { a=$1; b[$2]=$3; next; }
    $1==a { b[$2]=$3; f2=$2; next; }
    {
      printf "%s\t",a; 
      for(i=1;i<=f2;i++) { printf (b[i]) ? b[i] FS : "___" FS }
      a=$1;
      delete b;
      b[$2]=$3;
      print ""
    }
    END { 
      printf "%s\t",a; 
      for(i=1;i<=f2;i++) { printf (b[i]) ? b[i] FS : "___" FS }
      print ""
    }' file
fish    red     blue    ___     green
dog     blue    ___     yellow
cat     ___     ___     orange
```